# Deconstruct tuple from ref variable

Tags: c#, .net, valuetuple

I have the folloving method.

```
private ref (int, int) GetValue()
{
  var array = new (int, int)[1];
  return ref array[0];
}
```

The following code works fine:

```
var (s1, s2) = GetValue();
```

But i need to use the `ref` feature. The following code also works:

```
ref var r = ref GetValue();
```

Now i want to deconstruct the tuple. The following code won't compile:

```
ref var (r1, r2) = ref GetValue();
```

Is it possible to deconstruct `ref` variable?

Comment: Is `(int r1, int r2) = GetValue();` what you look for?

Comment: @SᴇM That is not a ref variable, as per the question. I do agree though that is what is necessary (as noted in my question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used `ref` value tuples yet, but in my understanding, not the contents of the tuple is `ref`, but the tuple itself. Therefore you need to specify an identifier, just as with `ref` arguments on a method for example.

Deconstructing the value tuple would mean the `ref` in your call is useless. The variables itself don't get updated with the `ref` tuple any more.

That would mean it makes perfectly sense to not allow this construction, and it doesn't seem possible to do so.